# Convert ByteBuffer to byte array java

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

Does anyone know how to convert ByteBuffer to byte[] array? I need to get byte array from my `ByteBuffer`. When I run `bytebuffer.hasArray()` it returns no. Every question I looked so far is converting byte array to byteBuffer, but I need it other way around.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `byteBuffer.array()`?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller - it will fail ... hasArray is returning `false`.

Comment: Yes i did with no success.

Comment: Ok.. I think nomis's answer will work :)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`ByteBuffer` exposes the bulk `get(byte[])` method which transfers bytes from the buffer into the array. You'll need to instantiate an array of length equal to the number of remaining bytes in the buffer.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ...
byte[] arr = new byte[buf.remaining()];
buf.get(arr);
```

Comment: Code only anwers are normally improved by adding some text explaining what the code is doing - can you add a bit of text to explain to the OP?

Comment: don't forget to call `buf.rewind()`, otherwise `buf.remaining()` will return with incorrect value

Comment: hi, buf.get(arr) still returns a ByteBuffer, is there any other alternative?

Comment: This is not converting the ByteBuffer to byte array. Its still returning ByteBuffer.

Comment: @SeetharamaniTmr - The bytes are being filled into "arr" variable and are not the returned value.

Comment: buff.array() should give you the array

Comment: `byte[] arr = new byte[ buf.position() ];  buf.rewind();  buf.get(arr)`

Answer (score 10):

If `hasArray()` reports `false` then, calling `array()` will throw an exception.

In that case, the only way to get the data in a `byte[]` is to allocate a `byte[]` and copy the bytes to the `byte[]` using `get(byte[])` or similar.