# YUV_420_888 to RGB conversion

Tags: java, image, computer-vision, rgb, yuv

I am working with camera2 and in ImageReader i have YUV_420_888 format. I looked around and found some formulas for converting it to RGB. But i have problem with some colors. Here is the code that converts it to RGB:

```
ByteBuffer buffer0 = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] Y1 = new byte[buffer0.remaining()];
buffer0.get(Y1);
ByteBuffer buffer1 = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
byte[] U1 = new byte[buffer1.remaining()];
buffer1.get(U1);
ByteBuffer buffer2 = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
byte[] V1 = new byte[buffer2.remaining()];
buffer2.get(V1);
int Width = image.getWidth();
int Heigh = image.getHeight();
byte[] ImageRGB = new byte[image.getHeight()*image.getWidth()*4];

for(int i = 0; i<Heigh-1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<Width; j++){
        int Y = Y1[i*Width+j]&0xFF;
        int U = U1[(i/2)*(Width/2)+j/2]&0xFF;
        int V = V1[(i/2)*(Width/2)+j/2]&0xFF;
        U = U-128;
        V = V-128;
        int R,G,B;
        R = (int)(Y + 1.140*V);
        G = (int)(Y - 0.395*U - 0.581*V);
        B = (int)(Y + 2.032*U);
        if (R>255) {
            R = 255;
        } else if (R<0) {
            R = 0;
        }
        if (G>255) {
            G = 255;
        } else if (G<0) {
            G = 0;
        }
        if (B>255) {
            R = 255;
        } else if (B<0) {
            B = 0;
        }
        ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4] = (byte)R;
        ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+1] = (byte)G;
        ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+2] = (byte)B;
        ImageRGB[i*4*Width+j*4+3] = -1;
    }
}
```

And when i point camera towards some color [this](https://postimg.org/image/5ynyma92h/) happens. Any idea why and how i can fix this?

EDIT: 
Here is code i used for posting on SurfaceView but i think its correct

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 

Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(ImageRGB));
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), true);
Canvas c;
c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
c.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
image.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look like the correct YUV->RGB transform.  The camera2 API color space for YUV_420_888 from the camera device is the JFIF YUV colorspace (same as what's inside JPEG files). This is unfortunately not clearly documented currently.

The JFIF YUV->RGB transform is defined to be as follows in the [JPEG JFIF specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf):

```
R = Y + 1.402 (Cr-128)
G = Y - 0.34414 (Cb-128) - 0.71414 (Cr-128)
B = Y + 1.772 (Cb-128)
```

So try that to start with. And for full clarify, Cb = U, Cr = V.

Comment: It's better but still not perfect. [Here](https://s14.postimg.org/pplh5spch/Screenshot_2016_11_30_23_26_13.png) is the link for image i get after changing. I will update original post for posting this on SurfaceView, maybe i did something wrong there too...

Comment: What are the problems with that image? There's nothing that immediately looks incorrectly colored to me or otherwise corrupt, but it's hard to tell since I don't know what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: Here i took two new images, [one](http://postimg.org/image/4ecm0k4lt/) with my camera app, [second](http://postimg.org/image/im2ap7hap/) is screenshot from my app. If you look at clouds you can see same color that appear on first picture of laptop, appear here but much less.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code

```
    if (B>255) {
        B = 255; //was R = 255;
    } else if (B<0) {
        B = 0;
    }
```

And try to use both of variants

```
R = Y + 1.402 * V
G = Y - 0.34414 * U - 0.71414 * V
B = Y + 1.772 * U
```

[Or from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.E2.80.B2UV420p_.28and_Y.E2.80.B2V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion):

```
R = yValue + (1.370705 * V);
G = yValue - (0.698001 * V) - (0.337633 * U);
B = yValue + (1.732446 * U);
```

Answer (score 0):

The U,V planes have dimensions (x, y/2) so try

```
int offset = (i/2)*Width + j;
int U = U1[offset]&0xFF;
int V = V1[offset+1]&0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found working solution in [Minhaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614250/minhaz) blog post: [How to use YUV (YUV_420_888) Image in Android](https://blog.minhazav.dev/how-to-convert-yuv-420-sp-android.media.Image-to-Bitmap-or-jpeg/) and slightly modified it for better performance.

If this was helpful to you, please send your thanks to @Minhaz.

```java
package YourPackage;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.media.Image;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class Convert
{
    // Based on: https://blog.minhazav.dev/how-to-convert-yuv-420-sp-android.media.Image-to-Bitmap-or-jpeg/
    //
    // With additions from:
    // - https://stackoverflow.com/q/40885602/
    // - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8394202/
    static public Bitmap YUV_420_888_to_ARGB_8888(Image image)
    {
        if (image.getFormat() != ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid image format (must be YUV_420_888)");
        }

        final int width  = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();

        // RGBA array, needed to construct Bitmap from it
        byte[] ImageRGBA = new byte[width * height * 4];

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        /*
            A YUV Image could be implemented with 'planar' or 'semi-planar'
            layout.

            A 'planar' YUV image would have following structure:
            YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
            ................
            UUUUUUUU
            ........
            VVVVVVVV
            ........

            While a 'semi-planar' YUV image would have layout like this:
            YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
            ................
            UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV   <-- Interleaved UV channel
            ................

            This is defined by row stride and pixel strides in the planes of the
            image.

            You can find by: image.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride(). If it's 2,
            the image format is 'semi-planar'.
         */

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        /*
            Extract Y/U/V planes bytes (via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744228/)

            For performance reason, we copy each plane bytes into related byte[]
            array. ByteBuffer `get()` method is too slow to use in a loop
            (possibly due to bounds checking):
                - `byte ByteBuffer::get(int index)`     --> Y_buffer.get(Y_index) --> slow
                - `byte byte[] operator [] (int index)` --> Y_bytes[Y_index]      --> fast

            Plane #0 is always Y;
            Plane #1 is always U (Cb);
            Plane #2 is always V (Cr);

            Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888
         */

        ByteBuffer Y_buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] Y_bytes = new byte[Y_buffer.remaining()];
        Y_buffer.get(Y_bytes);

        ByteBuffer U_buffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
        byte[] U_bytes = new byte[U_buffer.remaining()];
        U_buffer.get(U_bytes);

        ByteBuffer V_buffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
        byte[] V_bytes = new byte[V_buffer.remaining()];
        V_buffer.get(V_bytes);

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        // The Y-plane is guaranteed not to be interleaved with the U/V planes
        // (in particular, pixel stride is always 1).
        final int Y_RowStride    = image.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride();
        final int Y_PixelStride  = image.getPlanes()[0].getPixelStride();

        // The U/V planes are guaranteed to have the same row stride and pixel
        // stride.
        final int UV_RowStride   = image.getPlanes()[1].getRowStride();
        final int UV_PixelStride = image.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride();

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Reusable variables, stored here to not construct them in the loop.

        int Y_value = 0, U_value = 0, V_value = 0;
        int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;

        int Y_index = 0;
        int UV_x = 0, UV_y = 0, UV_index = 0;
        int pixel_index = 0;

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                Y_index = (y * Y_RowStride) + (x * Y_PixelStride);
                // Y plane should have positive values belonging to [0...255]
                Y_value = (Y_bytes[Y_index] & 0xff);

                UV_x = x / 2;
                UV_y = y / 2;
                // U/V Values are subsampled i.e. each pixel in U/V chanel in a
                // YUV_420 image act as chroma value for 4 neighbouring pixels
                UV_index = (UV_y * UV_RowStride) + (UV_x * UV_PixelStride);

                // U/V values ideally fall under [-0.5, 0.5] range. To fit them
                // into [0, 255] range they are scaled up and centered to 128.
                // Operation below brings U/V values to [-128, 127].
                U_value = (U_bytes[UV_index] & 0xff) - 128;
                V_value = (V_bytes[UV_index] & 0xff) - 128;

                // Compute RGB values from YUV.
                R = (int) (Y_value +  1.370705f * V_value);
                G = (int) (Y_value - (0.698001f * V_value) - (0.337633f * U_value));
                B = (int) (Y_value +  1.732446f * U_value);

                // Clamp R/G/B. Similar to: 'clamp(r, 0, 255)'
                R = R < 0 ? 0 : (R > 255 ? 255 : R);
                G = G < 0 ? 0 : (G > 255 ? 255 : G);
                B = B < 0 ? 0 : (B > 255 ? 255 : B);

                pixel_index = (x * 4) + ((y * 4) * width);
                ImageRGBA[pixel_index + 0] = (byte) R;
                ImageRGBA[pixel_index + 1] = (byte) G;
                ImageRGBA[pixel_index + 2] = (byte) B;
                ImageRGBA[pixel_index + 3] = (byte) 255; // A
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer( ByteBuffer.wrap(ImageRGBA) );
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```