# Accessing HardwareBuffer from ImageReader

Tags: android, camera

I am writing an Application for an Android device where I want to process the image from the camera.

The camera on this device only supports the NV21 and PRIVATE formats. I verified via the CameraCharacteristics and tried different formats like YUV_420_888 only for the app to fail. The camera HW Support is: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED

To create the CameraCaptureSession, I need to create an ImageReader.
To create the ImageReader I need to select the ImageFormat, in this case only PRIVATE works. If I try NV21, I get an error saying that it's not supported.

My onImageAvailableListener gets triggered but since the ImageFormat is PRIVATE, the "planes" attribute in the Image returns NULL.

According to the documentation, it's possible to access the data via the HardwareBuffer.

> Starting in Android P private images may also be accessed through
>   their hardware buffers (when available) through the
>   Image#getHardwareBuffer() method. Attempting to access the planes of a
>   private image, will return an empty array.

I do get an object of type HardwareBuffer when I get the image from the acquireLatestImage, but my question is: **How do I get the actual data/bytes that represents the pixels from the HardwareBuffer object?**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Lorek I just gave an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [HardwareBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/HardwareBuffer) documentation:

> For more information, see the NDK documentation for AHardwareBuffer

You have to use [AHardwareBuffer](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer) C language functions (using NDK) to access pixels of HardwareBuffer.

In short:

1. Create **native** JNI method in some helper class to call it from Java/Kotlin
2. Pass your `HardwareBuffer` to this method as parameter
3. Inside this method call `AHardwareBuffer_fromHardwareBuffer` to wrap `HardwareBuffer` as `AHardwareBuffer`
4. Call `AHardwareBuffer_lock` or `AHardwareBuffer_lockPlanes` to obtain raw image bytes
5. Work with pixels. If needed you can call any Java/Kotlin method to process pixels there (use ByteBuffer to wrap raw data).
6. Call `AHardwareBuffer_unlock` to remove lock from buffer

Don't forget that HardwareBuffer may be read only or protected.

Comment: Thank you, I am not working on that project anymore, we ended up going a different route to accomplish what we wanted.

Comment: Hey! I noticed that `AHardwareBuffer_lock` and copying the data into a `uint8_t` is **significantly slower** than using `getPlanes()[0].getBuffer()`. It takes almost 30ms, while the planes approach takes ~2ms. The logs say something about using Gr YUV access instead of hardware buffer locking... Any idea?

Comment: @mrousavy `getPlanes()[0].getBuffer()` only gets `ByteBuffer` not raw data. If you want to get data from ByteBuffer then you need to allocate byte array and copy data there (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744228/4915707). And after changes you must copy data back. These operations is slower than using lock.

Comment: I re-used an existing array for my memcpy, and I doubt that my memcpy takes 25ms. But I'll benchmark again to be sure about that, thanks.

Comment: Hey Alexander, I am using ImageWriter + MediaRecorder right now, and for some reason I cannot pass images through to MediaRecorder's surface. Do you maybe have any idea why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152531