# Java: Converting ByteBuffer multidimensional array

Tags: java

I have a ByteBuffer which has a multidimensional array of size `1x50176x3`. I wan to extract/convert this ByteBuffer back to array so that I can access certain elements in it. What is the most efficient way to achieve this? Following is the code I used to construct this ByteBuffer:

```
btBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * 50176 * 3 * 4); //Allocate Memory
btBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

putDataInBuffer(btBuf); //Call to put the data in above ByteBuffer
```

Comment: [Convert ByteBuffer to byte array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744096/convert-bytebuffer-to-byte-array-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the ByteBuffer is backed by an array with `hasArray` and if so convert it back with `array`. That is fast, but not all buffers are backed that way.

You can always convert the ByteBuffer to an array, but that is hardly efficient. I would instead convert it to a buffer of whatever your basic data type is (unless it is bytes in which case you are already set), for example with `asIntBuffer` for int. Then compute indexes manually and access the elements with `get(index)`.

For example with indexes x and y and z, the index can be computed as `x + y*width + z*width*height` where `width` is the x-dimension size and `height` the y-dimension size.

You may need to experiment to make sure that the way you compute your index is consistent with how the array does the job if you write to an array that you convert into a buffer.

EDIT: with allocateDirect your buffer is not backed by an array, so the second method is the one to use.