# How to convert libGDX's Texture to byte array and back again in Java

Tags: java, networking, serialization, libgdx, deserialization

So I'm working on a small multiplayer game using libgdx and java. I'm using datagram sockets and datagram packets to send messages between clients. In order to send data I need to convert it into a byte array. I've been searching to find a way to convert libgdx Textures to byte array but can't find the solution. I can't make the class implement Serializable since I have no access to the class.


I would greatly appreciate any help to fix my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't read it directly from texture try converting texture to Pixmap and read it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your `Texture` into a Pixmap with the following snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29451932/8178842):

```
Texture texture = textureRegion.getTexture();
if (!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
    texture.getTextureData().prepare();
}
Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
```

When you have got the `Pixmap` you can call the `getPixels()` method which will return a `ByteBuffer`, that includes the byte array of pixel data. You can read the raw data into a `byte[]` by calling the [get(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte%5B%5D)) method on the `ByteBuffer`:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = pixmap.getPixels();
byte[] pixelDataByteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(pixelDataByteArray);
```

To convert the `byte[]` back to a `Texture` you can use the constructors of `Pixmap` and `Texture` like this:

```
Texture fromByteArray = new Texture(new Pixmap(pixelDataByteArray, 0, pixelDataByteArray.length));
```

Comment: when I call the byteBuffer.array() java throws an Unsupported Operation Exception. Am I supposed to use a certain version of java?

Comment: `ByteBuffer` is an abstract class in Java. This means there can be several implementations of it, and it seems that the `Pixmap` uses one that doesn't support the `array()` method. But instead of using the `array()` method you can also read the bytes to an array using the `get(byte[])` method like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744228/8178842). I edited the answer accordingly.